I have a class dcat:Dataset defined in my ontology. How can I write SWRL rule in owlready using imported ontology class?
I have a class dcat:Dataset in the ontology. And the dataset has property such as,
fileObject = dcat.Dataset()
metric = dqv.Metric()
qmeasurement.isMeasurementOf.append(metric)
fileObject.hasFSA.append("FCBF")
....

with onto:
 rule = Imp()
 rule.set_as_rule(""" dcat.Dataset(?d), Covariance(?cov_metric), hasLowerLimit(?cov_metric, ?lower_limit) -> hasUpperLimit(?cov_metric, 10)""")

I would like to write a rule using explicitly defined vocabulary. However, I am failing to do so even after declaring and loading dcat ontology (or any other vocabulary such as dqv etc) in the workspace.  The properties and the classes which are defined using base ontology I can declare in
Hence, I am looking for a solution where I can write SWRL using externally defined vocabulary.
